# C# Reading HTML file produces random characters in whitespace

Tags: c#, html

I am using the WebBrowser control to view web pages that I have. The web pages are created by PDF and office files. I first open each office or PDF file and save it as an HTML page. I then navigate my control to the HTML page on my file system.

I want to allow the user to select text or graphs or entire tables and highlight them. so far I can get the text highlighted *BUT* it doesn't always work the first time.

I take the string value of what they highlight and do this

```
String substitution = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>" + SelectedText + "</span>";
```

Where *SelectedText* is what they selected in the control.

Then, I do this.

```
string htmlText = client.DownloadString(tempFileName);
htmlText = htmlText.Replace(SelectedText, substitution);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempFileName, false);
sw.Write(htmlText);
sw.Close();
```

Here's the problem, When I resave the file using *StreamWriter* - it adds special characters - in this case a weird looking "A"

How can I resolve this issue of introducing new characters?

[image]

Comment: Did you try different encodings?

Comment: no, which ones would i need and how/where do i add them?

Comment: `DownloadString` and `StreamWriter` both has overloads. And suggest you open the file with binary editor to see what  "A" actually is.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a text encoding (charset) issue.

### Solution 1

`StreamWriter` defaults to UTF-8.  The html files are most likely encoded in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

You need to determine the text encoding of the html file and then use it when creating the `StreamWriter`.

### Solution 2

It could also be an issue with `DownloadString` (if your are using WebClient).  Try setting the encoding

```
var client = new WebClient { Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 };
client.DownloadString(...)
```